# Microsoft Graph Java SDK - Unable to read shared files on Share point

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-files

Unable to handle / receive shared events on share point using microsoft graph sdk java. Already implemented webhook according to the official documentation on microsoft developer api. Let me know how can I get those details.

Alternatively is there any api which would return me all the shared data of the user on share point.

Comment: Refer the documentation Webhook supported resources (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#supported-resources), it clearly talks about that you can subscribe it to the root folder of a SharePoint/OneDrive for Business drive: /drive/root or Or to a specific resource instance: users/{id}, groups/{id}, groups/{id}/conversations, sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}, /communications/presences/{id} only. Not about the shared ones.

Comment: is there a way to get list of shared files in Share point

Comment: You can try this - GET /me/drive/sharedWithMe

Comment: I have tried it but throwing 403 forbidden

Comment: Sounds like you dont have necessary permissions, due to that you're getting HTTP 403. Check your token in https://jwt.ms and see if you necessary permissions/scopes part it; if not, try adding it and retry the call.

Comment: Does that helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Refer the documentation [Webhook supported resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#supported-resources), it clearly talks about that you can subscribe it to the root folder of a SharePoint/OneDrive for Business drive: /drive/root or Or to a specific resource instance: users/{id}, groups/{id}, groups/{id}/conversations, sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}, /communications/presences/{id} only and not about the shared ones.